# Reorder rows in a query TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a requirement to sort the rows returned from a table based on some condition.

For example, a simple select on a table produces following result. You see DisplayDayNumber starts from 1, and continues till 7.

[image: Following]

I want to sort the data so that row with DayOfWeekName = Tuesday appears first row, and rest of rows order themselves after it.

[image]

Any help to reorder these rows would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
...
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN DayOfWekName = 'Tuesday' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
    DisplayDayNumber ASC
```

**Update** So you want `Tuesday` first, but the rest of the rows should be ordered "naturally", so the next rows are `Wednesday`, `Thirsday`, `Friday` etc. until `Monday`?

You could use this query:

```
declare @weekStart varchar(10) = 'Tuesday'

SELECT d.*
FROM Dates d
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN DayOfWeekName = @weekStart 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN DisplayDayNumber < (SELECT DisplayDayNumber 
                                  FROM Dates 
                                  WHERE DayOfWeekName = @weekStart) 
        THEN 7 + DisplayDayNumber
        ELSE DisplayDayNumber 
    END ASC
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd6fb/7/0)**</kbd>

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but the query doesn't reorder rest of rows properly. e.g. Monday appears right after Tuesday as you can see below. 

    5 Tuesday      2
    1 Monday      1
    6 Wednesday    3
    7 Thursday     4
    8 Friday      5
    9 Saturday     6
    10 Sunday      7

I want monday to appear as last row, so following day order must be followed,

Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday.

Comment: For making Tuesday appear first, and Monday as last row - we'll need to remove DisplayDayNumber from order by. Now the desired row appears the first, and subsequest rows reorder themselves after specified row.

Comment: @suleman: i have edited my answer and added a demo, does it help?